# && command string question

Tags: command-line

So I was wondering if it would be possible to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo pm-suspend
```

As you can probably work out for yourself, I wish to update software when I go to bed, but have it suspend once it is done?

I would try it, but putting it bluntly, I'm afraid of breaking something.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The last `sudo` may ask for a password, if sudo times out during upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to type in your root password when you hit enter, but assuming `sudo pm-suspend` runs without errors normally, this will run just fine.

I suggest you run `sudo apt-get -y upgrade` so you don't have to go through the confirmation of the packages after it finishes with `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: So,
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo pm-suspend
? Sorry, I'm new to Linux

Comment: @Benabus I'd run it as:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade; sudo pm-suspend` just in case there are any errors in updating or upgrading, your computer will still go to sleep.